# How to get value for key in JSON list of {"k":foo, "v":bar} items using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, list, jq, key-value

Suppose I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "k": foo,
        "v": 1
    },
    {
        "k": bar,
        "v": 2
    }
]
```

How to get the value for the `"bar"` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select(expr)` to find the object with a key-value `"k":"bar"` and then you can extract the value of the `"v"` key.

```sh
$ jq . test.json 
[
  {
    "k": "foo",
    "v": 1
  },
  {
    "k": "bar",
    "v": 2
  }
]

$ jq -r '.[] | select(.k == "bar") | .v' test.json
2
```